# Php data not inserting into database

Tags: php

So for a few hours I have been trying to figure out why the data from my register page won't go into my database. I will list all the code and the database related to it here(I have to put it in pastebin or else it wont work:
http://pastebin.com/2sW701Qv is all the links, since I just made this profile and need more rep to post more link. 
Anyway thanks for trying to help, and I will respond to any questions!
Edit: in the registration file, the submit button has type set to data, not submit!

Comment: your code is really really terrible, you code has  **Deprecated API**,  and  **SQL Injection Vulnerability**

Comment: I know, before I do all that I have to make sure the basics are working,

Comment: here is a video to help show it! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Da5uHO9cdHM

Answer (score 0):

In Registration page

`$_POST['data']` is not set, therefore it's unable to reach the INSERT query.

**SOLUTION**

With submit button change the type to `submit` and name to `data`.

Your submit button should be `<input type="submit" name="data" value="Register" />`

Comment: is it coming inside insert condition? is it giving any error?

Comment: use `"INSERT INTO `users` (firstname, lastname, email, username, password) VALUES ('".$firstname."', '".$lastname."', '".$email."', '".$username."', '".$password."')"`

Comment: Still nothing happens.

Comment: please print `$query` and paste here.

Comment: In registration page where you have the code to insert the values in DB, there, `echo $query; exit;` after submitting the form and paste here the printed query so that I can have a look if the query is printed rightly.

Comment: <?php
 require('connect.php');
    if (isset($_POST['data'])){
        $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
  $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
        $username = $_POST['username'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];
 
        $query = "INSERT INTO `users` (firstname, lastname, email, username, password) VALUES ('".$firstname."', '".$lastname."', '".$email."', '".$username."', '".$password."')";
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        if($result){
            $msg = "User Created Successfully.";
        }
    }
    ?>

Comment: Please use `echo $query; exit;` after the line `$query = "INSERT INTO users (firstname, lastname, email, username, password) VALUES ('".$firstname."', '".$lastname."', '".$email."', '".$username."', '".$password."')"; ` and run your code. It will print a query on your browser. Paste that.

Comment: Oh, ok. It says this: INSERT INTO `users` (firstname, lastname, email, username, password) VALUES ('test', 'testing', 'test@test.com', 'test', 'testing')

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing..

this

```
if (isset($_POST['data'])){
```

to

```
if (isset($_POST['firstname'])){
```

and this

```
<input type="data" name="submit" value="Register" />
```

to

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" />
```

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your query with following :-

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `users` ('firstname', 'lastname', 'email', 'username', 'password') VALUES ($firstname, $lastname, $email, $username, $password)";
```

Comment: Can you replace these code and let me know your output
 $result = mysql_query($query) or die($query);

Comment: I did that, I don't know what you mean, but nothing changed, still does not work.

Comment: but what you got in your browser?

Comment: Nothing happens in my browser, just refreshes the page.

Comment: Oh, ok. It says this: INSERT INTO `users` (firstname, lastname, email, username, password) VALUES ('test', 'testing', 'test@test.com', 'test', 'testing')